# using QImage to display dpx or exr through QPixmap

Tags: pyqt4, qimage, qpixmap, qlabel

How do I display a exr or dpx file format image using QImage through QPixmap ?

Somebody told me QImage does the I/O operation for which plugins need to be installed !! this is really confusing me now.

Comment: please read the following docs:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files
and
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtimageformats/qtimageformats-index.html

Comment: @qurban : if I had to add support for exr and dpx file format where do I get plugins for it ? or is it possible if I can use it if they come with Photoshop or Foundry Nuke or Autodesk Maya ?

Comment: @san Ever found a solution or library for dpx into QImage?

Comment: @Maxito no, didnt find any.. if you want to push this on SO , you can can vote up the question and we might get someone's reply.